# %TIMESTAMP% syntax on WinSCP command-line in a batch file doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am trying to create a script that transfers a file from a local windows folder to a unix environment through SFTP. I made a slight change (concatenated `FX%timestamp%.txt`) to the code
so that the filename to be sent is equal to the date today.

The code already works when I copy these commands to the command prompt.
Result: Files get copied from `c:\upload` to `opt/dev/public_html/TEST/aperture/public/fx_rates`

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://ApertureUATusr:kiakit04@10.19.20.193/ -hostkey=""ssh-ed25519 256 f1:bd:8f:ad:ae:6f:93:a9:e5:ae:79:64:03:49:0a:09""" ^
    "lcd C:\upload" ^
    "cd /opt/dev/public_html/TEST/aperture/public/fx_rates" ^
    "put -transfer=ascii -permissions=0777 FX%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

The problem is that this code doesn't run as a .BAT file. I managed to get a screenshot when I run the batfile and as I checked the error, the system reads it as `FX.txt` instead of `FX20180221.txt`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [documentation for the WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

> To use `%TIMESTAMP...%` on a command-line in a batch file, you need to escape the `%` by doubling it to `%%TIMESTAMP...%%`, to avoid a batch file interpreter trying to resolve the variable.

So you need this:

```
    "put -transfer=ascii -permissions=0777 FX%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%.txt" ^
```